# How to solve Gradle error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, android

I am trying to ask user to enable GPS, I am new to app development I found some resources from internet of my requirement. I took code from one website and implemented on my app but when I try to build I am getting an error of `cannot find symbol`

See my java code below

```
package gps.gpstest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;
    private Context activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(!statusOfGPS) 
        {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
    }

    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.gps_disabled)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle(R.string.gps_disabled_title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.enable,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(
                                    @SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog,
                                    @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                                @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Errors during build process

`Error:(31, 73) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
Error:(44, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable cancel
Error:(35, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable enable
Error:(34, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled_title
Error:(32, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`

Help me out

Comment: Use MainActivity.this insted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error:(31, 73) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()

The **`getActivity()`** is used in **`fragments`** to get **`context`** not in activity

To get context in activity use

- **`this`**
- **`YourActvity.this`**
- **`getApplicationContext()`**

Use this

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Instead of this

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
```

> error: cannot find symbol variable enable Error:(34, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled_title Error:(32, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled

You need to create following resource in **`string.xml`** check [**`String resources`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource)

- `gps_disabled`
- `cancel`
- `enable`
- `gps_disabled_title`
- `gps_disabled`

Comment: Can you help me with these errors too
`Error:(44, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable cancel
Error:(35, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable enable
Error:(34, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled_title
Error:(32, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled`

Comment: @Jason sure i will try

Comment: I just commented you errors

Comment: @Jason check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Can you help me with these errors too `Error:(44, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable cancel Error:(35, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable enable Error:(34, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled_title Error:(32, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled`

Comment: builder.setMessage("Please Enable") //this line

Comment: .setTitle("GPS Disabled"));

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your errors:

> Error:(44, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable cancel
>
> Error:(35, 44) error: cannot find symbol variable enable
>
> Error:(34, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled_title
>
> Error:(32, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable gps_disabled

You're not accessing string resources correctly.
Instead of:

```
.setTitle(R.string.gps_disabled_title);
```

You should do:

```
.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.gps_disabled_title));
```

---

> Error:(31, 73) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()

As you're already on an activity, you should retrieve its context as follows:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
```